# Trying to write a Unix type shell in Python using fork, exec, and pid wait

Tags: python, shell, unix

I'm trying to write a Unix type shell in Python using `fork`, `exec` and `waitpid`. So far I have this code:

```
while True:
    pid = os.fork()
    command = os.getcwd() + ">"
    x = input(command)
    split_string = x.split(" ")
    if pid == 0:
        os.execvp(split_string[0], split_string)
    else:
        finish = os.waitpid(0, 0)
    print(finish)
```

However, it's not doing anything when I use it from a Unix shell.

Comment: It doesn't seem you have any way to break out of the loop. So "not doing anything" could be just stuck in an infinite loop. Can you give more context to how you are running this in your shell and what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your prompt (you named it `command`) gets printed twice. This is because the child process is stuck in its own prompt as it waits for a command to be typed. If you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once and then type your command (e.g. `ls`) followed by another press of <kbd>Enter</kbd> then your program works.

An easy fix for this is to put the call of `os.fork()` after the prompt:

```python
import os

while True:
    command = os.getcwd() + ">"
    x = input(command)
    split_string = x.split(" ")
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        os.execvp(split_string[0], split_string)
    else:
        finish = os.waitpid(0, 0)
    print(finish)
```